# Searching in Dynamo DB with AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I want to search in Dynamo DB on multiple columns without using partition key.

I am trying to implement the use case as we have in mysql like we can search over any column with a column type value. But, as i got to know that the same use case can't satisfied by Dynamo DB.

IS there any way to achieve this in Dynamo DB.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query)

Comment: You need to scan if you would to filter the data without the partition key. Refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan

Answer (score 0):

You can support arbitrary searches if you index the contents of your table using a DynamoDB Stream and an AWS Lambda function that writes table updates to an AWS ElasticSearch cluster.

Answer (score 0):

As Per Example Given In AWS Document of [Local Search Indexes - PHP Low Level API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSILowLevelPHP.Example.html) ,

> Valid comparisons for the sort key condition are as follows:
>
> - sortKeyName = :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is equal to :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName < :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is less than :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName <= :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is less than or equal to :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName > :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is greater than :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName >= :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is greater than or equal to :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName BETWEEN :sortkeyval1 AND :sortkeyval2 - true if the sort key value is greater than or equal to :sortkeyval1, and less than
>   or equal to :sortkeyval2.
> - begins_with ( sortKeyName, :sortkeyval ) - true if the sort key value begins with a particular operand. (You cannot use this function
>   with a sort key that is of type Number.)
>
> **Note** that the function name begins_with is case-sensitive.

So, only **AND** supported for ranges. **There is no OR**. Also you could try using **begins_with**.

Your Scenario Can be converted to following Code :

```
$tableName = "genericTable";
$response = $dynamodb->query([
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'IndexName' => 'OrderCreationDateIndex',
    'KeyConditionExpression' => 'hashkey = :h_key and columnName = :value',
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  [
        ':h_key' => ['S' => 'foo'],
        ':value' => ['S' => 'bar']
    ],
    'Select' => 'ALL_PROJECTED_ATTRIBUTES',
    'ScanIndexForward' => false,
    'ConsistentRead' => true,
    'Limit' => 5,
    'ReturnConsumedCapacity' => 'TOTAL'
]);
```